# How to trigger a 400 Bad Request using a question mark or backslash

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, http, iis

[`requestPathInvalidCharacters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters.aspx) specifies a list of invalid characters, which will trigger a `400 Bad Request` response. By default, the list consists of: `"<,>,*,%,&,:,\\,?"`. This includes question marks and backslashes. But as far as I've seen, both characters will never be seen as invalid.

Every URL character after the first question mark will be used in the query string. So URLs like `/path?foo?bar` are considered valid. In this example the query string consist of a single keyless value `foo?bar`. Even `/?????` is a valid URL.

Backslashes are automatically converted to forward slashes, so I don't see how those could be considered invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Just a `%` will trigger an error. E.g. `GET /% HTTP/1.1` as it is a incomplete request.

For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/%

Some of the other characters do trigger 400 responses, but your browser translates them automatically. Proof of concept:

```
% curl -i 'http://stackoverflow.com/<'
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: I know `%` and `<` can trigger 400 responses, they're in `requestPathInvalidCharacters` by default. But why are `?` and `\\` in there? How can they trigger 400 responses?

Comment: This is an guess, but I'm assuming they are qualifying that `?` is part of the request query, not path. My only guess on `\\\` is RFC2396 defines it as requiring escape due to being a delimiter, and it is not a valid.